# How to cd to a directory on remote machine and run the script present in that directory

Tags: ssh

When I do this

```
ssh host@someip "cd /target && ls"
```

the files on remote machine are displayed.

Now, I am trying to run a file on the remote machine.

```
ssh host@someip "cd /target && ./file.sh"
```

When i do this it reaches the folder named target on the remote machine but the file is executed on local machine. How to make file.sh also run on remote machine ?

Comment: try  ssh host@someip "cd /target && sh file.sh" ?

Comment: @tianwei it says there's an error in file.sh ... But when I manually run it on remote machine it worked.

Comment: *"the file is executed on local machine"* what makes you think?

Comment: @Jakuje Actually when I run the file manually on a local machine I get error. I can see the same error.

Comment: Some libraries aren't supported. @Jakuje

Comment: Can't it be that they are not supported on both local and remote host?

Comment: @Jakuje When I open the remote machine's terminal and manually run the file, it executes without any error !

Comment: omg, but it does not mean that it runs on the local machine.

Answer (score 2):

It depends where do you initialize your libraries on the remote server. There are several possibilities, which can be wrong, but without exact error, it is impossible to guess:

1. Your `~/.bashrc` (or other startup files) do not load libraries for non-interactive jobs. You can force TTY allocation:

   ```
   ssh -t host@someip "cd /target && ./file.sh"
   ```
2. You might initialize libraries with in some other script. You can load it before running your script:

   ```
   ssh host@someip "source your_init_file && cd /target && ./file.sh"
   ```